# Centering table horizontally within page using threeparttable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, threeparttable

I’m sure this has been addressed somewhere before, but I’m having difficulty finding the answer and would greatly appreciate some help. I’ve tried inserting \centering or using the center environment in various places and can’t seem to figure it out.

I’m trying to center the table within the page, but it seems like the use of threeparttable pushes the table to the left - causing it to start immediately after the left margin. I want the distance from the table to the left edge of the page to be equal to the distance from the table to the right edge of the page. Here’s an example of my current setup:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review, 12pt, times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}  % has commands for singlespacing, onehalfspacing, and doublespacing
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}  % These 3 lines define new column types mainly to allow for centered column of user defined width
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}      % Supresses page number 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\bfseries{\footnotesize{Table 1. Test Table.}} \\ [2mm]
\scriptsize
\normalfont
\begin{tabular}[pos]{L{7.0cm} R{2.0cm}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Dependent Variable: Outcome Var} \\ 
\midrule
$Variable 1$ & 0.123 \\
& (1.00) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 2$ & 0.456 \\
& (1.65) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 3$ & 0.789 \\
& (1.96) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 4$ & 1.123 \\
& (2.59) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 5$ & 1.456 \\
& (3.00) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 6$ & 1.789 \\
& (3.20) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 7$ & 2.000 \\
& (3.50) \\ [10.0mm]

Some Info & Yes \\ [0.5mm]
Other Info & No \\ [0.5mm]
Observations & Ample \\ [0.5mm]
Random Statistic & 1,505.37 \\ [0.5mm]
Last Piece of Info & 100.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\centering
\caption{
\normalfont{\textnormal{This table displays information. It is just being used to see if I can actually center this thing, which has proved more difficult than anticipated. }}}
\label{tab:Test}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you use `threeparttable`, since you have no tablenotes?

Comment: What is `[pos]` in `\begin{tabular}[pos]{L{7.0cm} R{2.0cm}}` supposed to do?

Comment: I had used the threeparttable, because it seemed to be an easier way to ensure the table caption is the same width as the table. I think I forgot to delete the [pos] from code that was copied from another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- There's no `\centering` instruction between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{threeparttable}`.
- A `threeparttable` environment has three [surprise!] formal components: a caption, a `tabular` (or `tabular*`, or `tabularx`, etc) environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. With this in mind, the instruction

  ```
  \bfseries{\footnotesize{Table 1. Test Table.}} \\ [2mm]
  ```

  is out of place. You should either remove it or incorporate it in the `tabular` environment.

With these two adjustments, your formatting objective will be achieved immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I had tried placing the centering command there before, but maybe I had other issues at the time that prevented everything from compiling the way I wanted it. Also, good point on the the placement of the Table 1 heading. I moved it to within the tabular environment, which seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review, 12pt, times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}  % has commands for singlespacing, onehalfspacing, and doublespacing
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}  % These 3 lines define new column types mainly to allow for centered column of user defined width
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}      % Supresses page number 

\begin{document}
\oddsidemargin = 4cm

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\bfseries{\footnotesize{Table 1. Test Table.}} \\ [2mm]
\scriptsize
\normalfont
\begin{tabular}[pos]{L{7.0cm} R{2.0cm}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Dependent Variable: Outcome Var} \\ 
\midrule
$Variable 1$ & 0.123 \\
& (1.00) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 2$ & 0.456 \\
& (1.65) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 3$ & 0.789 \\
& (1.96) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 4$ & 1.123 \\
& (2.59) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 5$ & 1.456 \\
& (3.00) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 6$ & 1.789 \\
& (3.20) \\ [1.5mm]
$Variable 7$ & 2.000 \\
& (3.50) \\ [10.0mm]

Some Info & Yes \\ [0.5mm]
Other Info & No \\ [0.5mm]
Observations & Ample \\ [0.5mm]
Random Statistic & 1,505.37 \\ [0.5mm]
Last Piece of Info & 100.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\centering
\caption{
\normalfont{\textnormal{This table displays information. It is just being used to see if I can actually center this thing, which has proved more difficult than anticipated. }}}
\label{tab:Test}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

% What I did was added `\oddsiemargin =4cm`. After table ended, one has to set `\oddsidemargin=0`

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't center table  but change page layout: move text area to the right for 4 cm. Meaning, that left border of text will align with left border of table and will spill out of page on the right side. Adding `\oddsidemargin=0pt` after table just restore original page layout with table started at left border. Do you test your solution?